# how find key wih one element(value) in c# linq

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have next dictionary in c#

```
Dictionary<int, List<int>> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();
```

{1, 1,2,3,4
2, 4,5,6,7
3, 1}

And i want to find elements which have only one element on list(last in dictionary).
How can i do it?

Comment: Will have to find those elements frequently? Or just once in a large timespan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way:

```
Dictionary<int, List<int>> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();

List<KeyValuePair<int, List<int>>> result = dictionary.Where(keyValuePair => keyValuePair.Value.Count == 1).ToList();
```

What is happening?

`dictionary.Where` | search in `dictionary` for

`keyValuePair =>` | a `KeyValuePair` which i will refer with the name `keyValuePair`

`keyValuePair.Value` | which has its value (which is a `List<int>`)

`keyValuePair.Value.Count == 1` | with a `Count` equal to `1`

`.ToList()` | then return a list containing the matched `KeyValuePairs`

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:

I just realized you want to find the key.

```
List<int> result = dictionary.Where(x => x.Value.Count == 1).Select(x => x.Key).ToList();
```

This should be the one you are looking for then

ORIGINAL:

I believe you are looking for something of this sort, using LINQ:

```
IEnumerable<List<int>> result = dictionary.Values.Where(x => x.Count == 1);
```

If you want to have it in List I'd consider enumerating the collection.

```
List<List<int>> result = dictionary.Values.Where(x => x.Count == 1).ToList();
```

Hope this answers your question.